# Limit to Black Star, Black Souls, Recharging enchanted weapon during civil war

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I started the civil war thinking I'd level my enchanting pretty quickly by using a weapon enchanted with soul trap with the black star and constantly recharge the weapon after every kill.  In theory this should result in lots of recharging for each quest.  However what has actually happened is that this theory works for something like the first 5 enemies and then after that none of the enemies result in a soul capture.  I've tried switching back and forth between a soul trap bow and soul trap sword to no avail.  I've tried switching to a bound sword with the soul trap perk, still no souls after the first 5 or so.

Is this a bug?  Is there any way around it?